# Regarding compute table statistic in spark

Tags: pyspark

I am working on a pipeline which ingest huge amount of data ..around 80 M records daily. the Main Table where these records are inserted has total around 173M records . Do you think its a good idea to run analyze table to compute table statistic before and after insertion of Millions on records using spark-sql?